# TYPO3 extbase FAL file download

Tags: download, typo3, extbase

Using Extbase plugin, I wanted to show file download link.
I am using TYPO3 v6.1 FAL file structure.
But I am unable to get original file download link.

In file ext_tables.sql

```
CREATE TABLE tx_myext_domain_model_test (
    # ...
    files varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    # ...
);
```

In file Configuration/TCA/Test.php

```
$TCA['tx_myext_domain_model_test'] = array(
    // ...
    'files' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'Files',
        'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
            'files',
            array(
                'appearance' => array(
                    'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
                ),
            ),
            $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
        ),
    ),
    // ...
);
```

In file Classes/Domain/Model/Test.php

```
class Test extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
{
    // ...
    /**
     * Files
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference>
     */
    protected $files;

    /**
     * Returns the files
     *
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference> $files
     */
    public function getFiles()
    {
        return $this->files;
    }       
}
```

In file Classes/Controller/TestController.php

```
class TestController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{
    // ..
    public function listAction() {
        $tests = $this->testRepository->findAll();
        $this->view->assign('tests', $tests);           
    }
    // ..
}
```

In file Resources/Private/Templates/Test/List.html

```
<f:for each="{tests}" as="test" iteration="itemIterator">
    <f:debug title="Debug of test">{test.files}</f:debug>
    <f:for each="{test.files}" as="file">
    <a href="{f:uri.image(src:file.uid,treatIdAsReference:1)}">
        <f:image src="{file.uid}" alt="" width='101' height="67" treatIdAsReference="1"/>
    </a>
    <p>{file.originalResource.originalFile.title}</p>
</f:for>
```

Here If in debug "originalResource" is NULL.
Anybody know how to get original file link here ?
Thank you.

Comment: As this are file references, you might need to resolve the references.

Comment: Why do you need the originalResource property? Do you want to get the title of the file? What do you mean with original file link?

Comment: Hi Shufla, I need to get the file name and also the file path, so the file can be downloaded using a href tag. I meant original file link means the file path that stored in sys_file table. So I can wrap that link in a href tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
public function getFiles() {
    $result = array();
    foreach($this->files as $file) {
        $result[] = $file->getOriginalResource();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Completely untested.

Comment: Hi pgampe, I have tried your code, still "originalResource" array is null

Comment: Are you sure that this files contains anything at all?

Comment: yes. This code gives the png image of a file.
<a href="{f:uri.image(src:file.uid,treatIdAsReference:1)}">
     <f:image src="{file.uid}" alt="" width='101' height="67" treatIdAsReference="1"/>
   </a>

For displaying and downloading images, its ok.
But pdf also dispalying as png file, because of image tag.

Comment: Strange! started working now.
<a href="fileadmin{file.originalFile.identifier}">{file.originalFile.name}</a>

Comment: @Ganybhat I'm at the same point - PDFs are rendered as images. What did you do to display their URL as link? My "originalResource" is also empty.